# Which method is more user friendly to add groups in particular section?

Tags: ux-field

I am working on financial web application.
I have group set which contains number of groups. Those group sets are mapped to sections (mapping is many-to-many). I can see group sets in the drop down list.
I can add new group set by clicking on "new group" link or icon.
I can add inline groups with all the information. For adding a group, I have to add all the information for group then it will add.

I can add new group set by clicking on link then pop-up will open and I have to give name and one group to add group set.
After adding group set, I can add number of groups inline for that group set.

[image]

I can add new group set by clicking on an icon then pop-up will open and I have to give name and one group to add group set.
After adding group set, I can add number of groups inline for that group set.

[image]
Which way is more user friendly and simple to understand?

Comment: In your second example it seems like you can have all the groups displayed from multiple group-sets simultaneously. I believe it can be very lengthy and the user may lose focus browsing through all the entries. Is there any need for having several group-sets displayed at the same time or is it enough to display only one group-set at a time (like in the first example)?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your user has to interact with the following objects:

- Sections
- Group Sets and Section it belongs to
- Groups and Group set it belongs to

If we were to reduce the number of decisions to be made at the moment of adding a new group, then option 1 is the best. As with one click, you have made two categorization choices (Add a group to this section and this groupset). This will also reduce error rates.

In the end, it will depend on how users are performing the tasks: many groups added to a groupset? or many groups added to different groupsets?
If unsure, another option is to make it possible to move the group to a different groupset after it has been created.